# Long running CSV download works with Chrome but not Postman/application

Tags: api, google-chrome, postman

I have a legacy REST API that allows downloading of CSV files which it generates from a database.
Sometimes, the SQL is long-running and won't return any data for 5 minutes, then it starts to stream out the data.

For some reason, my application that consumes this API, as well as Postman, can't handle this 5-minute scenario. It eventually closes the connection and no data is received.
However, using Google Chrome works fine. It idles for that 5 minutes or so, then data starts to slowly download. It also seems to work using CURL.

I have analyzed and compared the HTTP headers between Chrome and Postman, and they seem to be identical (including Keep-Alive/timeout, etc..). How is Chrome able to stream data with a longer idle time? How can I change my application or Postman to negotiate the connection more smoothly like how Chrome and Curl seem to be able to?